# How to get actual client's IP when both client and host are in VPN?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ip-address, vpn

I have an intranet website and everyone has to VPN to access this website. So when logging client's IP, I'm just getting their VPN IPs (which are same for all).

How can I get their actual IP addresses? Like from [this example](http://www.whatismyip.com/).

I read several questions/answers but it looks like there're no solutions for this specific case. They have solutions if requests are coming through a proxy, but not for VPN...

Does anyone experience this case?

Comment: Look at the VPN server logs

Comment: I don't understand how you plan to do that from behind a VPN. It kind of defeats some of the purposes of a VPN

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the only thing you can get is the internal IP address.
If you are on the same VPN you share the same public IP (assuming there is only one VPN server)